# axis scale in cubism context in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, cubism.js

I have been playing around with cubism and wanted to give try to stock example at http://bost.ocks.org/mike/cubism/intro/demo-stocks.html
The csv files have 1280 values for each stock with last value from May 1, 2012 but the displayed timeline shows till Augsut 2012. I understand the step size of 1280 did not pick all the values as there were holidays in between so there is difference in last 1280 values in files and the values displayed. What is start value for timeline (today, may1,2012) and what is role of .serverDelay(new Date(2012, 4, 2) - Date.now()) in timeline display? It is not so clear from API at https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Context#wiki-scale. 
The plot in presentation (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/cubism/intro/) seems to show the 1280 days from May1,2012. Most likely I am missing something very simple here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it seems no one else has insight to offer and I'm working on this too at the moment. Have you checked out the [cubism.Context documentation](https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Context)? It includes definitions of these methods.

I believe some of the trouble with this particular example is that it is making use of csv files rather than the graphite/cube database system cubism.js is designed to work with. So it may be that the serverDelay is completely irrelevant in this case.

Comment: This should be a comment to the OP question as it does not answer it

Comment: yes, sorry. That makes sense, but I don't see any option to comment on a question.

Comment: Right under the question there is an **add comment** link in light gray

Comment: I don't meet [the rep. threshold](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) to comment, apparently. Anyway, sorry I didn't have a better answer, but I thought my input was better than nothing for the OP.